# Predict should return zero if no train data available in one numeric feature column

Tags: tensorflow, predict, feature-engineering

I try to predict if an article is sold or not.

I have a DNNLinearCombined Classifier with description, category, size, price, etc. And the label 0 for not sold and 1 for sold.

```
    sold    description category_id size_id gender  price   host_id lat long    year    month
0   1   [dünne, jacke, gepunktet, , , , , , ]   9   25  f   3.5 1   48.21534    11.29949    2019    3
1   1   [kleid, pudel, dunkelblau, gepunktet, , , , , ] 9   25  f   4.0 1   48.21534    11.29949    2019    3
2   0   [kleid, rosa, hum, hund, katze, , , , ] 9   24  f   4.0 1   48.21534    11.29949    2019    3
3   1   [kleid, hum, blau, elsa, und, anna, , , ]   9   24  f   4.0 1   48.21534    11.29949    2019    3
4   0   [kleid, blue, seven, lachsfarben, , , , , ] 9   23  f   4.5 1   48.21534    11.29949    2019    3
```

```py
text_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key='description',                                                     vocabulary_list=list(word_index))
text_embedding = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(text_column, dimension=50, combiner='sqrtn')

CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['category_id', 'size_id', 'host_id']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['price','lat', 'long', 'year', 'month']
feature_columns = []

for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  vocabulary = dftrain[feature_name].unique()
  feature_columns.append(feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))

est = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(linear_feature_columns=feature_columns, dnn_hidden_units=[100],dnn_feature_columns=[text_embedding],
    n_classes=2,
    dnn_optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.003))
```

The problem is that price as numeric column has very less impact to the prediction because some articles with same price are sold and some not. But in general the price should be in same region as the sold articles for same category, size and similar description. For example if an article has price of 2€ the prediction is 39,6%, but if I set price for same article to 100€,the prediction is 39,4%. But this is not correct, it must be below 1%. No other article in the training data had such high price.

How can I define the price column that the complete prediction goes nearly to zero if no training data with nearly same price is available?

Thanks

Comment: What is 39,4%? The  accuracy of your predictions ? Please show some of your code in order to see the settings, that might be useful. You mean you change 2€ to 100ç in the test set, right? Can you provide a sample of your training set ?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu I added some code example.  39,4% is probability to be label 1 (sold) and if the price is too high. Not in range of trainingset the probability should be nearly to zero.

Comment: What do you mean by "nearly same price " in tour last phrase ?

Comment: For example in category 9 and size 26 I have prices from 0.5€ to 15€ then it is possible to sold articles in this category and size around 0.5€ to 20€, but everything with an higher price has much less possibility to sold

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas here :

1. You should consider "year" and "month" as categorical features, not numeric. They are categorical ordinal features, not scalars.
2. Why don't you try and use DNNLinearCombined Regressor ? It will predict a value between 0 and 1 and you should find the right limit in order to decide if the prediction is 0 or 1.
3. If the month number have a meaning, you may try to use [time series](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series), and not regression. I suggest you merge the features "year" and "month" into one feature of type date or integer (set an unique integer value for each date).
4. If you still want to use a Classifier, be careful to ballance your training data before.

Comment: 1. The idea was that older entries get less weight. For the month if for examples ski clothes will sell good in months 9-11, but not in 3-4 and if I set it in categorie column month 3 and 4 are totally different for the network or not? 2. Is there technically a different between classifier and regressor? I thought Classifier only calculate possibility for each label and then takes the label with the highest possibility.

Comment: A classifier clasifies into 0 or 1, and yes it predicts for both classes and takes the highest prediction. A regressor will predict a number, not a class. If you make regression in your case the prediction will be a number between 0 and 1. After that you must make a choice according to a limit, for example set to 1 if prediction > 0.5 and set to 0 if prediction < 0.5. Here, the limit is 0.5, but you may choose another one.

Comment: About the months now, you state that old prediction sell less, so sells will be better in months 9-11 than in 3-4, but what that means also that it will sell good in 9/2015 and even better in 2/2016, and here 9>5, so it will not work. You should better merge the columns month and year, and fill it with a date or with an unique numeric identifier -- type will be date ot numeric. I shall update my answer too.

Comment: If products sell well if the price is lower, you do not have to bother about that; The training program will learn that accordingly. That is the very purpose of machine learning, training according to the data. But if you still do not have the good result, keep in mind that you have other features than price and they have their weights too. If you are still not satisfied it means that you need to clean/preprocess your data again.